Meaning of たり here
From Kokoro chapter 1,

その中に知った人を一人ももたない私も、こういう賑やかな景色の中に裹まれて、砂の上に寝そべってみたり、膝頭を波に打たしてそこいらを跳ね廻るのは愉快であった。

What たり is doing here? In modern Japanese, I sometimes notice that in ～たり～たりする constructions, the last たり can be omitted so it becomes ～たり～する instead. So, I wonder if it's it supposed to be understood as

その中に知った人を一人ももたない私も、こういう賑やかな景色の中に裹まれて、砂の上に寝そべってみたり、膝頭を波に打たしたりしてそこいらを跳ね廻るのは愉快であった。


Your interpretation is grammatically possible but would result in "to frolic around while lying down or (while) letting waves hit my knees". However, it's impossible to frolic around while lying down. Here, the two actions of the たり-marked list are 寝そべる and 跳ね廻る. The sentence can be rephrased as follows:

砂の上に寝そべってみたり、膝頭を波に打たしてそこいらを跳ね廻ったりするのは愉快であった。
It was enjoyable to lie down on the sand, or to frolic around with waves hitting my knees.

